# SR Latch using Circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz, draw, circuits

I am trying to draw an SR Latch using Circuitikz

My code is:

```
\begin{circuitikz} \draw
(0,2) node[nor port] (NOR1) {}
(1,2) node[anchor=east] {Q}
(1,0) node[anchor=east] {$\overline{Q}$}
(0,0) node[nor port] (NOR2) {}
(NOR1.in 1) node[anchor=east] {R}
(NOR2.in 2) node[anchor=east] {S}
(NOR1.out) -| (NOR2.in 1) 
(NOR2.out) -| (NOR1.in 2) 
;\end{circuitikz}
```

[image]

I would like the image be something like:

[image]

I don't know how to make the circuit paths look like that

Comment: Provide a [Minimum Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/28557). From `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`

Answer (score 4):

In future, please add a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/28557) as part of the question. including `\documentclass`, `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`. Something like this:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz} \draw
(0,2) node[nor port] (NOR1) {}
(1,2) node[anchor=east] {Q}
(1,0) node[anchor=east] {$\overline{Q}$}
(0,0) node[nor port] (NOR2) {}
(NOR1.in 1) node[anchor=east] {R}
(NOR2.in 2) node[anchor=east] {S}
(NOR1.out) -- ++(0,-0.5) -- ($(NOR2.in 1) +(0,0.5)$) -- (NOR2.in 1)
(NOR2.out) -- ++(0,+0.5) -- ($(NOR1.in 2) +(0,-0.5)$)--(NOR1.in 2)
;\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

And the output:

[image]

Comment: What does it mean -- ++ ? I don't understand how you use it. Is there a documentation that you recommend that explains all of that?

Comment: @Delfin `(a) -- ++(1,0)` is equivalent to `(a) -- ($(a)+(1,0)$)`. It draws a line from coordinate `(a)` to another coordinate which is 1 unit shifted along x and 0 unit shifted along y.

Comment: What is --? And what is -|? Sorry, I'm complety new in circuitikz. There is an official manual http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/circuitikz/circuitikzmanual.pdf But I don't find in which part they explain that

Comment: @Delfin  `circuitikz` lodas `tikz`.  `--` and `-|` are defined in `tikz`.Please go through the [Minimal introduction to TikZ](http://cremeronline.com/LaTeX/minimaltikz.pdf) and then the [manual](http://mirror.iopb.res.in/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf).